# Creating a heatmap from 3 vectors

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization, matlab-figure, heatmap

I would like to create this kind of heatmap, given 3 vectors X,Y,Z. How can I do this?

[image: heatmap]

So far I have only been able to create a scatter plot and adding a colorbar

```
V = table2array(CouplingandSynchdata)
for i = 1:30                 
    x(i,1)=V(i,1)
    y(i,1)=V(i,2)
    z(i,1)=V(i,3)       
end


V= '[1.629 1.812 0.342;0.583 1.207 0.867;0.636 0.904 0.805;1.016 1.713 0.579;0.507 1.905 0.851;1.5 0.839 0.314;1.726 0.761 0.501;0.493 0.341 0.696;0.672 1.907 0.814;1.145 1.988 0.575;0.468 0.101 0.419;0.645 0.101 0.379;0.948 1.04 0.669;0.189 0.796 0.894;0.467 1.611 0.829;0.623 0.213 0.401;0.886 0.798 0.423;0.001 1.05 0.9;0.869 1.071 0.742;0.948 1.73 0.65;0.882 0.858 0.67;0.356 1.765 0.889;0.111 0.002 0.751;0.45 1.39 0.883;0.371 0.007 0.792;0.08 0.34 0.878;0.374 0.757 0.529;0.539 1.866 0.751;0.008 1.457 0.899;0.008 0.242 0.847]'

c = colorbar;
c.Label.String = 'C';
scatter(x,y,20,z,'filled');
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
c = colorbar;
grid on;
view(0, 90)
```

Comment: The desired result looks like a [surface plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) with no edges, and using the "[inferno](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps)" colormap.

Comment: Can you help doing it? My vectors X,Y,Z are of lenghts 30.

Comment: I do not know how to create the grid to plot these 3 vectors

Comment: Usually some combination of `meshgrid` and `griddata` is required. Can you please [edit] your question and add the input vectors? You can do `mat2str(V)`.

Comment: I have added the vectors

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you need a 2d data to create a visualization like you want, but you have only some scattered points. If you want a continuous visualization, you have no choice but to interpolate it somehow. Here's an example of one of the many ways this can be done:

```matlab
function q65059500
%% Create data:
V = [1.629 1.812 0.342;
     0.583 1.207 0.867;
     0.636 0.904 0.805;
     1.016 1.713 0.579;
     0.507 1.905 0.851;
     1.5   0.839 0.314;
     1.726 0.761 0.501;
     0.493 0.341 0.696;
     0.672 1.907 0.814;
     1.145 1.988 0.575;
     0.468 0.101 0.419;
     0.645 0.101 0.379;
     0.948 1.04  0.669;
     0.189 0.796 0.894;
     0.467 1.611 0.829;
     0.623 0.213 0.401;
     0.886 0.798 0.423;
     0.001 1.05  0.9;
     0.869 1.071 0.742;
     0.948 1.73  0.65;
     0.882 0.858 0.67;
     0.356 1.765 0.889;
     0.111 0.002 0.751;
     0.45  1.39  0.883;
     0.371 0.007 0.792;
     0.08  0.34  0.878;
     0.374 0.757 0.529;
     0.539 1.866 0.751;
     0.008 1.457 0.899;
     0.008 0.242 0.847];
   
V = sortrows(V,[1,2]);
x = V(:,1);
y = V(:,2);
z = V(:,3);


%% Plot the original data:
% Create a figure
hF = figure('Position', [395,55,1328,320]); hAx = gobjects(3,1);

hAx(1) = subplot(1,3,1); 
scatter3(hAx(1), x, y, z, [], z, 'filled');
view(0, 90); axis square;
title(hAx(1), 'Original data');

%% Interpolate using griddata:
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(x,y);
ZZ = griddata(x,y,z,XX,YY);
hAx(2) = subplot(1,3,2); scatter3(hAx(2), XX(:), YY(:), ZZ(:), [], ZZ(:), 'filled');
view(hAx(2), 48, 40);
title(hAx(2), 'Gridded data');

%% Interpolate using a surface fit (Code auto-generated by MATLAB):
[xData, yData, zData] = prepareSurfaceData( x, y, z );
ft = fittype( 'poly55' );
fitresult = fit( [xData, yData], zData, ft );
% Plot fit with data:
[Xq,Yq] = meshgrid(0:0.001:2, 0:0.001:2);
hAx(3) = subplot(1,3,3); 
surf(hAx(3), Xq, Yq, fitresult(Xq,Yq), 'EdgeColor', 'None');
zlim(hAx(3), [0, 1]); view(hAx(3), 0, 90);
colormap(hAx(3), inferno); colorbar(hAx(3));
title(hAx(3), 'Poly55 interpolated');

%% Adjust colors etc.:
colormap(hF, inferno());
set(hAx, 'CLim', [0,1]);
for id = 1:numel(hAx)
  colorbar(hAx(id));
end
xlabel(hAx, 'g_n');
ylabel(hAx, 'g_l');
zlabel(hAx, 'mMIR');
```

(`inferno` comes from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/a60db2ad-074c-49cf-8354-6af17ee2d1ff/4ca0929f-e627-48a5-9964-e48e88923a28/files/Colormaps%20(5)/Colormaps/inferno.m)).

Resulting in:

[image]

While the rightmost chart surely looks impressive, you must remember that interpolation might lead to completely incorrect results, so **be careful** to choose an interpolation scheme that makes sense for your problem!

Comment: Can I have a plot like the third one without interplotation, but just with my data? Cause I will gather more data in the future

Comment: @Fras If you're not interpolating, what do you intend to plot in the spaces between your measured points? Your data does not come in the form of an image (like your example), so if you want to turn it into an image you'll have to specify a value for each combination of (x,y). The best you can do without interpolation is a denser version of the central plot.

Comment: @Fras does this solve your problem? If so, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/).